# What is a 'management and investment' structure in this Luxembourg visa?

Tags: investing, investment-strategies, visa

I was curious about some of the investment Visa programmes in Europe. I came across this page on the Luxembourgish government site: https://guichet.public.lu/en/entreprises/creation-developpement/projet-creation/entree-sejour/investisseur-pays-tiers.html

The third option seems to be particularly confusing because I am not sure what a "management and investment structure" is supposed to mean.

> at least EUR **3 million** in a management and investment structure, either existing or still to be created, with its registered office in Luxembourg where it must have and maintain the necessary substance or;

Does anyone know what this might be? What's even more interesting is that there is no time period for how long one needs to invest unlike other options on the page.

Comment: Great question.  I **think** they mean: item 2 is "a business" (example, restaurant), but item 3 you refer to is when you have an "investing company" that invests in a number of businesses willy-nilly, rather than literally owning/running "a business".  note that the "investment company" itself must have a real office and at least two really real employees.

Comment: Do note that it's both "hard and easy" to get in to Luxembourg.  Everything's done on personalish value judgements. If you come from a normal "by the books" typical country, it can be trippy  :)

Answer (score 3):

*In my reading* the difference between the

- 1/2 million deal

and the

- 3 million deal

is essentially that in the 1/2m deal you can get away with **5 employees** (so, start a restaurant or web design shop with 5+ employees),

but in the 3m deal you can get away with only **2 employees** (so, you open an "investing concern", ie you have an office - with two employees - and you sit around and spend your $3m on investing in various businesses in the area).

So you either go 1/2m, but pay 5 every year, or, 3m, paying only 2 every year.

These particular golden visa schemes from .lu are quite new so there's not much info on them. Unlike long-established golden visa schemes, where there is a wealth of info.

With almost all golden-visa schemes, the political pretense is you are "creating jobs", so that's the key to success in these. (Observe the 20m ! deal, where you don't have to create any jobs! Whoa!)

---

One point BTW, Luxembourg is very "human". In most jurisdictions you can meet these requirements very *nominally*. So, you dig up some paperwork showing that you have (barely) employed 2 people and you rent a closet for an office. In .lu, actual humans will just look at what's going on and giggle if you try to do a "paper" rather than a real business/investment/whatever.

---

**A whole "6" issued! (Not 6,000 .. 6 !)**

FWIW this article mentions .. http://delano.lu/d/detail/news/luxembourg-issued-6-golden-visas/203060

Comment: Wow I thought it only meant I could invest 3M in any company that maintains a "natural substance" in Luxembourg. This is more complicated than it seems.

Comment: Right: I can tell you ***for certainty*** it absolutely does ***not*** mean that.  Also yes, golden visas are very hard indeed  :O

Comment: Just a minor point, note that you will pay 10, 20, 30 thousand to a fixer in Luxembourg to make this happen.  (Assuming it can be pulled-off.)

Comment: When you say "giggle" you might want to clarify that this means *deny* the application.